# linux can send fn key and disable touchpad?

Tags: linux, touchpad

I am using a laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 and I want to send a <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> from a script in order to disable my touchpad.

When i type the command `xdotool key fn`, it prints

```
(symbol) No such key name 'fn'. Ignoring it.
(symbol) No such key name 'fn'. Ignoring it.
```

How can I send the Fn key?

----------------------------update June 13 ----------------------------------

So the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key can't be sent via program language? By looking at `/usr/include/linux/input.h` line 614 , I see:

```
#define KEY_FN 0x1d0
```

it also don't work by sending signal? Or it isn't the Fn key code?

----------------------------update June 26 ----------------------------------

in rencently, I did some test about <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> using C . I cat `/dev/input/event3` and can see the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> code is `240` which is

```
#define KEY_UNKNOWN     240
```

and some other code. I'm feeling blue. Maybe the touchpad is handled directly by the hardware as user49740 had said.

but the command can disable touchpad  by os

```
xinput set-prop 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad' 'Device Enabled' 0
```

however it can't change the touchpad light status. And the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> can't enable or disable the touchpad .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pressing the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key does not send any keycode to the operating system, therefore you cannot fake pressing the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.

However, some <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>another key</kbd> combinations send keycodes. For example, the play/pause/next/prev key combos always send keycodes

From a terminal, you can run the `xev` program, which opens a simple window. You can now press various keys and key combos and the keycodes received by `X11` will be shown in the terminal. You can press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> and see if `xev` shows any output

Unfortunately, on most laptops the 'disable touchpad' key combo is handled directly by the hardware, so you must find another way to disable the touchpad.

If you are using a Synaptics touchpad, you should look at [synclient](http://linux.die.net/man/1/synclient) or [syndaemon](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/syndaemon1.html). For example, [this article](http://www.rvdavid.net/disabling-the-laptop-touchpad-in-ubuntu-linux/) says that `synclient TouchpadOff=1` turns off the touchpad and `synclient TouchpadOff=0` turns it on

Answer (score 7):

No. The <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is handled by hardware, not the OS.

Comment: so, the Fn key don't work using program language? only by hardware ?
But I see C++ source code at line 614 in /linux/input.h .
#define KEY_FN  0x1d0
it also don't work by sending signal? Or it isn't the Fn key code?

Comment: Then, How come that Fn-F8 doesn't work with Linux, on my laptop ?

Answer (score 0):

**You can send Fn key on Linux by xdotool on follow way:**

**If you like to send:**

```
xdotool key Fn + Up
```

You can do it on follow way:

```
xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessUp
```

**If you like to send:**

```
xdotool key Fn + Down
```

You can do it on follow way:

```
xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessDown
```

I hope this help you by your reseach for sending the rest of possible key combination by xdotools.